# D3 Line Chart- Line Not Scaling properly (ClipPath, Zoom)

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am using D3 version 4 to parse through data and graph by date.

I have scaled everything to work nicely with zoom, however I cannot seem to keep the line from overflowing outside of the axes. I would like it to stay inside the chart and just cut off parts when the user zooms in.

Using a clip path, the lines/dots are cut off at the axes boundary, but when the user zooms in they overflow past but are still missing the original piece that was cut off (i.e. only half of a dot, just bigger and overflowing).

The whole project is viewable here: https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/NzMVjj

Here are some important/relevant pieces:

```
// scale, set ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width-100])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.inspected_at; }));

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range( [height, 0])        
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; }));

var zoom = d3.zoom()  
    .scaleExtent([1, 40])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
////  clip path  
defs = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 0)
    .append('defs')

defs.append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'clipper')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

//append line
svg.append('g')
    .append("path") 
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipper)')
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line(data))
    .attr("stroke", "blue")

function zoomed() {
     svg.selectAll(".line")
        .attr("transform", d3.event.transform); 
     svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("transform", d3.event.transform); 
     gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)))
     gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzzGWY). I slightly changed how lines and circles are appended, and bound the clip path to a `g` group which houses the line/circles.

```
svg.append('g')
  .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipper)') .selectAll('path.line').data([data])
    .enter().append("path") 
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("stroke", "blue");    
// draw the plot data
svg.append('g').attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipper)') .selectAll("circle.dot")                                 
        .data(data)                                         
      .enter()
```

This way it clips the entire grouping.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Sounds like I was struggling with managing my g groups and the parent/child relationship between elements. I also subtracted 100px from the clip width so it didn't overlap with my legend. Thanks again!